# How to use replace function in when condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a condition in where clause of my store procedure.I want to apply replace function after THEN on @LastName and @FirstName

This is my code

```
   AND IN2.LNameTxt LIKE CASE WHEN @LastName IS NOT NULL THEN (@LastName) ELSE IN2.LNameTxt END
   AND IN2.FNameTxt LIKE CASE WHEN @FirstName IS NOT NULL THEN @FirstName ELSE IN2.FNameTxt END
```

I want @LastName or @LastName.Replace("''","") after THEN any suggestion how can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the following will meet all your requirements, but it should help some:

```
Declare @LastName varchar(20) = '''''Smith'
/* Use the statement below as a test of replacing the variable 
Select REPLACE(@LastName, '''''', '')
*/
Select * 
from Your.Data.Source IN2 
where 
    IN2.LNameTxt Like 
        CASE 
            WHEN @LastName Is NOT Null THEN Replace(@LastName, '''''', '') 
            Else IN2.LNameTxt --Not sure why you want this here?
        End
```

Comment: I need both Replace(@LastName, '''''', '') or @ LastName

Comment: How do you mean you need both?  What is the OR based on?

Comment: Suppose If some one enter don's i need to get result for don's as well as don

Comment: That is a total different question @JuniorDev.  Look at the SOUNDEX() and DIFFERENCE() functions.  http://craftydba.com/?p=5211 It compares how close two words sound.

Comment: Crafty DBA has you on the right track if you are wanting to see if a string sounds like something else.  What I provided just strips out a series of quotes from a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the COALESCE() function.

I do not understand why you are comparing a field to itself as a default.

Also, I could not tell what character you wanted to replace.  I assumed it was a double quote.

```
 AND IN2.LNameTxt LIKE REPLACE(COALESCE(@LastName, IN2.LNameTxt, ''), '"', '')
 AND IN2.FNameTxt LIKE REPLACE(COALESCE(@FirstName, IN2.FNameTxt, ''), '"', '')
```

Comment: I want to put this condition IN2.LNameTxt = @LastName or IN2.LNameTxt= replace(@LastName,'''','') here

Comment: But that does not match the logic above.  Choose @LastName or LNameText, what ever one is not null.  Then remove the double quote.  You have to decide on what you want for business logic.  If you change it the TSQL will have to change.

Answer (score 0):

See the TechNet article on SQL Server `REPLACE` function: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

Also, I think you want to use this pattern instead. It should perform much more efficiently.

```
AND 
(
    @LastName IS NULL --if @LastName param is null then do not filter on last name
    OR
    IN2.LNameTxt LIKE REPLACE(@LastName, 'SearchForText', 'ReplaceWithText') 
) 
AND 
(   @FirstName IS NULL --if @FirstName param is null then do not filter on first name
    OR
    IN2.FNameTxt LIKE REPLACE(@FirstName, 'SearchForText', 'ReplaceWithText') 
)
```